# How to draw roof plan layout without any API

Tags: mathematical-optimization, autocad, vector-graphics, revit-api

I'm trying to draw roof plan layout with only lines is there any logic or mathematical calculations needed to draw   roof plan without any software only with code,below is the example[image]

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the slope is the same on each side, the hips are the bisectors of the eaves.
[image]

The generic way is to use elevation views.
[image]

Comment: Thank you for above solution,does the same approach would work when we have different slope ?  Also can we use these for complex roof with different height and slope?